# What's the cleanest way of accessing a NSOutlineView from a NSTableCellView?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

From within a view-based cell I need to find out if it's 'expanded' for which I need access to the parent NSOutlineView. What is the best way of accessing the parent table view? Do I store a reference to the table inside the cell or is there a better way of doing this? I hate using [super... super...] from within cells as that can break at any time in the future.

Comment: I think the super, super (but with checking) approach is probably the only way.

Comment: You're doing something wrong. Rethink your approach. You may get the "extended" status when doing `itemForObject` or another delegate method.

Comment: itemForObject simply only gives me the item not the view. You can only check if it was expanded/collapsed using the view. Obviously I could store the status inside the actual object/item but that looks wrong too. Just like [anyView window] gives you the parent window I don't think there's anything wrong in trying to obtain the parent table the row belongs to (as that is the only view it will ever belong to)